# Creating a matrix of validation results with correct counts

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a trained 10-class machine learning model similar to an MNIST digit classifier. I want to determine how often each digit class is correct and, if a mistake is made, which class it is confused for. I want to use this to create a confusion matrix, among other things.

Anyway, the input for each pass is a batch of pictures from the validation set (shape (32,3,224,224) where 3, 224, and 224 are the picture dimensions and 32 is the batch size) and the labels (shape 32,1) of class numbers those pictures match. The model output is (shape 32,1) and lists the class numbers the model thinks they best match. I can easily find how many matches there are by comparing the labels and outputs tensors, but I am having a hard time telling *how* the misclassifications are missed. Here's a snippet from the main validation loop

```
# Main validation loop
valid_accuracy = 0.0
model.eval()
device = 'cuda'
raw_counts = torch.zeros((11,11)) # leave room for totals in the last row and column
with torch.no_grad():
    for inputs, labels in validloader:
        # Run each image through the network to get log probabilities of each class
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        logps = model.forward(inputs)  

        # Calculate accuracy
        ps = torch.exp(logps) # 32 X 10: probability of each label in every case
        top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim=1)
        equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
        valid_accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()

        # Count confusions
        raw_counts[labels[:],top_class[:,0]] += 1  # <<<<---- This is the problem!

        # Accumulate letter-by-letter certainties
        for i in range(ll):
            sum_ps[i,] += sum(ps[labels==i])
            letter_counts[i] += len(ps[labels==i])

# Print validation accuracy
valid_accuracy = valid_accuracy/len(validloader)
print(f"Validation accuracy: {valid_accuracy:.3f}")
```

The problem is where I try to count the confusions. With only ten classes and a batch size of 32 I am guaranteed to have repeated labels. But saying `raw_counts[labels[:],top_class[:,0]] += 1` only increments by one each row of the `raw_counts` matrix. For example, in the debugger just before this line:

```
(Pdb) top_class[:,0]
tensor([5, 9, 5, 0, 2, 3, 3, 8, 2, 9, 6, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4,
        5, 3, 6, 5, 0, 3, 2, 1], device='cuda:0')
(Pdb) labels[:]
tensor([5, 9, 5, 0, 2, 3, 3, 8, 2, 9, 6, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4,
        5, 3, 8, 5, 0, 3, 2, 1], device='cuda:0')
(Pdb) raw_counts
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Everything is as expected. But after executing the line:

```
(Pdb) n
> /home/model.py(219)main()
-> for i in range(10):
(Pdb) raw_counts
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Even though five labels in this batch are 5's and the model got them all right, still `raw_counts[4,4] == 1`. Is there any pythonic way to count all five correct answers without messy for loops and the like?

Answer (score -1):

Haven't enough reputation to comment, so I'll duplicate [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089379/12451452).

---

I use these 2 functions to calc confusion matrix (as it defined in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)):

```py
# rewrite sklearn method to torch
def confusion_matrix_1(y_true, y_pred):
    N = max(max(y_true), max(y_pred)) + 1
    y_true = torch.tensor(y_true, dtype=torch.long)
    y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred, dtype=torch.long)
    return torch.sparse.LongTensor(
        torch.stack([y_true, y_pred]), 
        torch.ones_like(y_true, dtype=torch.long),
        torch.Size([N, N])).to_dense()

# weird trick with bincount
def confusion_matrix_2(y_true, y_pred):
    N = max(max(y_true), max(y_pred)) + 1
    y_true = torch.tensor(y_true, dtype=torch.long)
    y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred, dtype=torch.long)
    y = N * y_true + y_pred
    y = torch.bincount(y)
    if len(y) < N * N:
        y = torch.cat(y, torch.zeros(N * N - len(y), dtype=torch.long))
    y = y.reshape(N, N)
    return T

y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]

confusion_matrix_1(y_true, y_pred)
# tensor([[2, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1],
#         [1, 0, 2]])
```

Second function is faster in case of small number of classes.

```py
%%timeit
confusion_matrix_1(y_true, y_pred)
# 102 µs ± 30.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
confusion_matrix_2(y_true, y_pred)
# 25 µs ± 149 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: If you can copy an answer from another question to answer this question, then this question is a duplicate and should be closed. Or alternatively if they are different questions, your answer doesn't really answer one of them.