# Faster method of computing confusion matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, metrics, confusion-matrix

I am computing my confusion matrix as shown below for image semantic segmentation which is a pretty verbose approach:

```
def confusion_matrix(preds, labels, conf_m, sample_size):
    preds = normalize(preds,0.9) # returns [0,1] tensor
    preds = preds.flatten()
    labels = labels.flatten()
    for i in range(len(preds)):
        if preds[i]==1 and labels[i]==1:
            conf_m[0,0] += 1/(len(preds)*sample_size) # TP
        elif preds[i]==1 and labels[i]==0:
            conf_m[0,1] += 1/(len(preds)*sample_size) # FP
        elif preds[i]==0 and labels[i]==0:
            conf_m[1,0] += 1/(len(preds)*sample_size) # TN
        elif preds[i]==0 and labels[i]==1:
            conf_m[1,1] += 1/(len(preds)*sample_size) # FN 
    return conf_m
```

In the prediction loop:

```
conf_m = torch.zeros(2,2) # two classes (object or no-object)
for img,label in enumerate(data):
    ...
    out = Net(img)
    conf_m = confusion_matrix(out, label, len(data))
    ...
```

Is there a faster approach (in PyTorch) to efficiently calculate the confusion matrix for a sample of inputs for image semantic segmentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use these 2 functions to calc confusion matrix (as it defined in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)):

```py
# rewrite sklearn method to torch
def confusion_matrix_1(y_true, y_pred):
    N = max(max(y_true), max(y_pred)) + 1
    y_true = torch.tensor(y_true, dtype=torch.long)
    y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred, dtype=torch.long)
    return torch.sparse.LongTensor(
        torch.stack([y_true, y_pred]), 
        torch.ones_like(y_true, dtype=torch.long),
        torch.Size([N, N])).to_dense()

# weird trick with bincount
def confusion_matrix_2(y_true, y_pred):
    N = max(max(y_true), max(y_pred)) + 1
    y_true = torch.tensor(y_true, dtype=torch.long)
    y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred, dtype=torch.long)
    y = N * y_true + y_pred
    y = torch.bincount(y)
    if len(y) < N * N:
        y = torch.cat(y, torch.zeros(N * N - len(y), dtype=torch.long))
    y = y.reshape(N, N)
    return y

y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]

confusion_matrix_1(y_true, y_pred)
# tensor([[2, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1],
#         [1, 0, 2]])
```

Second function is faster in case of small number of classes.

```py
%%timeit
confusion_matrix_1(y_true, y_pred)
# 102 µs ± 30.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
confusion_matrix_2(y_true, y_pred)
# 25 µs ± 149 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: return y instead of T in confusion matrix 2

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Grigory Feldman for the answer too!
Mr.O and I made with numpy.

```
# weird trick with bincount
def confusion_matrix_2_numpy(y_true, y_pred, N=None):
    y_true = y_true.reshape(-1)
    y_pred = y_pred.reshape(-1) 
    if (N is None):
        N = max(max(y_true), max(y_pred)) + 1
    y = N * y_true + y_pred
    y = np.bincount(y, minlength=N*N)
    y = y.reshape(N, N)
    return y
```

Please try this.
When you use a known class_num, it can be even faster.
One thing I should mention is that there can be cases where the max value does not match the original number of classes.
For instance, when the batch size is small and the confusion matrix is integrated for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Grigory Feldman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12451452/grigory-feldman) for the answer! I had to change a few things to work with my implementation.

For future lookers, here is my final function that sums up the percentages of each confusion matrix over a batch of inputs (to be used in training or testing loops)

```
def confusion_matrix_2(y_true, y_pred, sample_sz, conf_m):
    y_pred = normalize(y_pred,0.9)
    obj = y_true[y_true==1]
    no_obj = y_true[y_true==0]
    N = torch.tensor(torch.max(torch.max(y_true), torch.max(y_pred)) + 1,dtype=torch.int)
    y_true = torch.tensor(y_true, dtype=torch.long)
    y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred, dtype=torch.long)
    y = N * y_true + y_pred
    y = torch.bincount(y.flatten())
    if len(y) < N * N:
        y = torch.cat((y, torch.zeros(N * N - len(y), dtype=torch.long)))
    y = y.reshape(N.item(), N.item())
    y = y.float()
    conf_m[0,:] += y[0,:]/(len(no_obj)*sample_sz)
    conf_m[1,:] += y[1,:]/(len(obj)*sample_sz)
    return conf_m

...
conf_m = torch.zeros((2, 2),dtype=torch.float) # two classes (object or no-object)
for _, data in enumerate(dataloader):
    for img,label in enumerate(data):
        ...
        out = Net(img)
        conf_m = confusion_matrix(out, label, len(data))
        ...
    ...
```

Comment: `normalize` not defined. Did you mean `y_pred = (ypred>0.9).float()` ?

Comment: Plus this implementation gives NaNs.